# Android. ConstraintLayout: constraint end not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, margins, chain

I need to create chain with `ConstraintLayout`.I want the TextView to be attached to the left side, the text is immediately followed by a `ImageView`, and another `ImageView` is attached to the right side of the screen. See an example.

[image]

If the `TextView` contains long text, I need the text to go to another line. That is, so that the `TextView` does not overlap with the image view on the right, but is limited to margin. See an example.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_first"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivSecond"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_second"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If the text is not long, then everything works well, but if the text is long, then it is superimposed on the `ImageView` and goes beyond the screen. I tried to use chain but nothing worked. Please, help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by fixing `ivSecond` to the end of the parent and then creating a horizontal chain of `tvTitle` and `ivFirst`, so long as you apply  a `packed` chain style and a bias of `0` to the chain and use `constrainedWidth` on the text view.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivFirst"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="hello world"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivSecond"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the text is short, the first image is right up against it:

[image]

When the text is long, the first image stops at the edge of the second image and the text wraps to another line:

[image]

Comment: I want to achieve something like this but, without pink box at the end.
the blue box only be stick at the end when text is too long.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with `layout_constrainedWidth` . For this your text view needs to be constrained horizontally . try the layout below i have made few changes in it .

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivFirst"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFirst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivSecond"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tvTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSecond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, in this case, the ivFirst is not located immediately after the text, but is located on the right in front of the ivSecond.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that . I completely forgot about that I was in bit of hurry . Well Ben provided you the answer for same .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) to wrap the `tvTitle` TextView & the `ivFirst` ImageView; So that it controls to wrap the content of the `TextView` to the next line and avoid pushing the `ivFirst` to the right/end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:alignContent="center"
        app:alignItems="center"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:flexWrap="nowrap"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivSecond"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivSecond"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
            app:layout_flexShrink="10000" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFirst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_first"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_second"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also make sure to add the gradle dependency at module level:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
```

Preview:

[image]